# How can I get tensorflow to work on eclipse?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a student in high school trying to get tensor flow to work but when asking my teacher for assistance I get yelled at and told to just try harder. I have no clue what to do.

I want to use tensor flow on eclipse using python 3.7 and tensor flow 0.12.0

Tensorflow is in the library and installed through pip, but when trying to import it, it throws an error.

import tensorflow as tf

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application
>   Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python3.7-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\CSLAB-SERVER\home\CollinsC\My Documents\ISMWorkspace\ISMMMM\src\tensorflowtesting.py", line 6, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 60, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3.7-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "\cslab-server\home\CollinsC\Application Data\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

Comment: Why are you using TF 0.12? That is horribly outdated. I don't think it's compatible with Python 3.7.

Comment: Also, are you using a CPU with AVX?